# Android ListView shows empty content

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a fragment with a listview. The adapter only has one field: the item id.

When I add an item to the list using the adapter, the list shows the item id.

But if I put a simple item id check before (a for-cycle that checks if the item id is equals to one specific id, if so then adds the item id), the list shows an empty row (like it added something) but without showing the item id.

What could be? I'm sure that the "check part" works.

**EDIT**: I forgot to specify that the item id is a String.

**EDIT 2**: I added the check part of the code. It loops through `list` that contains the item ids that I want to add to the other fragment list. `item` is the item that I'm checking. `blueF` is the fragment.

```
for(int i=0; i<list.getCount();i++) {   
  if(list.getItem(i).equals(item.getId())) {
    //send the item to the listview of the fragment
    blueF.getArrayAdapter().addItem(item);
    break;
  }
}
```

**EDIT 3**: After some testing, I discovered that the listview inside the fragment have inside the item (I used getCount and also printed the item id), but it isn't showing the item id! My custom adapter have a notifyDataSetChanged() in the "add" method and I've also recalled the `notifyDataSetChanged` after the call to the add method in the activity...but nothing.

**EDIT 4**: Probably is some problem with the layout?
I have this layout for the list row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/inventory_item_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inventory_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:typeface="monospace" >

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inventory_item_counter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the fragment layout with the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView

    android:id="@+id/listBlueTagView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Did you also verify that the check was true so it indeed did add the item into the list?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: sorry but I can't show you the code. I'm sure that the check was true. I've added also a second (integer) field in the same row. The adapter adds 1 row, put the integer in it but not the item id.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understood this,

Try this in your main Activity, these are just Pseudo codes there may be some typos.

```
public class Main extends Activity{
EditText etID; //Your Item ID field.
ListView listView; // Listview in your XML.
int check_ID; // ID which you want to compare with Edit Texts' value.
List<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Your_Layout_XML);

etID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID); //ITEM_ID editText id in XML
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_ListView_ID);
check_ID = 1; // suppose you want to add into your list if user enters 1 in editText as Item ID
if(check_ID = Integer.parseInt(etID.getText().toString())) //get value from EditText then check it with your desired value and on being equal add item to list
// add item here and set it to listView
arrayList.add("Mango");
ArrayAdapter<String> array_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             arrayList);

     listView .setAdapter(array_Adapter ); 


 } else{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong ITEM ID",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks.
so basically you suggest to do the check "int vs int" not "string vs string" right?

Comment: You said ID? in your question, you can also compare string with little tweaks.!
Compare strings like this.

String ID="WhatEva";
if(id.equals(editext.getText().toString()){  do your work here }

Answer (score 0):

Your filter code should be done before setting the Data of the Adapter, so the Adapter have only the items that it will show.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint, but i can't do it (if I understand what you say),because i must add dinamically other items

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved the problem.

It was a graphic problem generated in the `getView` of the adapter. Basically, some elements overwrote the color text of the ID, rendering it invisible.

I set the text color to `Color.BLACK` and now I can see the ID of the item.